# Android: How to call function inside Application class every 5 minutes in background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, kotlin-coroutines

I want to start refresh `Service` within my app. What I want to achieve is to do API call every 5 minutes even if user locked his screen to update data and especially visible Notification by recreating Notification with new data from API call.

I tried to move my logic to Application class where I will initialize `Job` within `GlobalScope`, which will run indefinitely until I cancel this `Job`. This solution works if I set delay to 10 or 30 seconds. It is working even if my App is in background. But if I set delay to way longer period (which I need in this case) like 5 - 10 minutes, it will suddenly stop. My understanding is that this Job will die down or Application class is destroyed when there is long inactivity.

I would like to create Service which will communicate with my Application class and initialize this Job within Service to call Application class function to refresh Notification. But I cant use parameters in Service.

Is there any way how to link Application class and Service?

I don't need to run this refreshAPI if App is killed.

Example(this is running within Application class - want to move it to Service and call app.callRefreshAPI() from Service class):

```
var refresher: Job? = null
private var refreshRate = 300000L
fun createNotificationRefresher(){
    refresher = GlobalScope.launch {
        while (isActive){
            callRefreshAPI()
            delay(refreshRate)
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: CountDownTimer solution (not working):

```
var refresher: CountDownTimer? = null
private var refreshRate = 300000L //5min
private var refresherDuration = 780000L //12min
fun initNotificationRefresher(){
    refresher = object : CountDownTimer(refresherDuration, refreshRate) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            callRefreshAPI()
        }
        override fun onFinish() {
            initNotificationRefresher()
        }
    }.start()
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** Timers/jobs/workers are not working when phone screen is locked and OS is in a sleep mode. That means there is no way to use timers in a background-background operations. I had to use BroadcastReceiver registered in Application class (NOT! AndroidManifest) and listen to SCREEN_ON action. Then saving time when user unlocked his phone and checking if it was at least 5-10 minutes between screen lock which updated notification and under this condition refresh Notification by calling API in GlobalScope.

I hope this will be helpful for others. Job/Timer will work if Application is in background and user is still interacting with phone (Checking other App, browsing stuff etc.).

Comment: Why not try WorkManager for the repetitive task? It will run whether your app is in foreground or in background? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager
You can use other methods, for eg. EventBus to communicate the result of the service to your application. Safe and Easy!

Comment: How to send Application class object as constructor parameter to my Worker class? I have to run callRefeshAPI within Application class. Only thing I want to set is time interval when to run it. PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder allows me only add class::java object into constructor not whole Worker object

Comment: Also PeriodicWorkRequest interval is 15 minutes at min. Its too long for my refresh.

Comment: If all you care is to run the refresh task when the App is in foreground, you may use OneTimeRequest and reschedule the task again when the refresh has been done. And you DON'T pass the application object. Use EventBus's eventing mechanism to trigger the task.

Answer (score 1):

you can use CountDownTimer for that. and Create an IntentService class and Run that service for API call.

> JAVA

```
public void repeatCall(){

   new CountDownTimer(50000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {
           repeatCall();//again call your method
        }

    }.start();

}

//Declare timer
CountDownTimer cTimer = null;

//start timer function
void startTimer() {
    cTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
        public void onFinish() {
        }
    };
    cTimer.start();
}


//cancel timer
void cancelTimer() {
    if(cTimer!=null)
        cTimer.cancel();
}
```

> KOTLIN

```
 fun repeatCall() {

        object : CountDownTimer(50000, 1000) {

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                repeatCall()//again call your method
            }

        }.start()

    }
```

Comment: This is not working if phone screen is locked. Not even single refresh and nothing in logs that onTick was called

Comment: Added code. CountDownTimer is recreated every 12 minutes. Refresh worked if I was in App for 5 minutes with preventing my device to sleep and automatically locking a screen after

Comment: I guess similar problem than coroutines and jobs. CountDownTimer is not working in background

Comment: I will actually have to use AlarmManager to force device to wakeup every 5 minutes because Android is killing every background task if device is in sleep mode. Thats how Push notifications work and also local notification fired at certain time in a future

Answer (score 1):

Though calling an API after every 5 minutes is not the most optimized way to do the task.
The minimum value is 15min for periodic jobs. 
You can use

[Ever Note Android Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) Library for that.

```
private void schedulePeriodicJob() {
    int jobId = new JobRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.TAG)
            .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
            .build()
            .schedule();
}
```